# Book from 1970s/80s where the sun was dimmed

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember a book from the 1970s-1980s where something like "dimming the sun" was done to disastrous results? Scientists sprayed something in the atmosphere. Not Snowpiercer :-) . Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sure the scientists deliberately did it? Otherwise, Jack Vance’s Dying Earth stories/books take place in the future where the sun has dimmed and threatens to go out.

Comment: Meanwhile, [life imitates art](https://www.straitstimes.com/world/europe/scientists-weigh-up-stratospheric-sunlight-barrier-to-curb-global-warming)

Answer (score 2):

This could possibly be the novel Sunstrike by George Carpozi. it features a rogue scientist creating a shield in space that blocks the light from the sun and causes a mini ice age. Here is a link to the book available via amazon, [https://www.amazon.com/Sunstrike-George-Carpozi/dp/0523403658](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0523403658)